# Armv8 Assembler optimization

Tags: c++, arm, computer-vision, inline-assembly, armasm

Hello I did my first assembler implementation on an Raspberry Pi 3. I would like to ask you how I can improve the algorithm. What it basically should do is:
in an 320x240 uint8_t array it analyses every point and create two bit masks out of it. The bit masks are created by comparing the center point to the so rounding pixels on a circle with a radius of 3. If the pixel on that circle is smaller then the center minus a threshold value the regLO mask gets a 1 otherwise 0. If the pixel on that circle is larger then the center plus a threshold value the regHI gets a 1 otherwise 0. After every comparison both regHi and regLO are shifted by one. So that we get in the end a bitmask with lower and higher pixels.
This algorithm builds the preparation for the FAST-9 algorithm.

[EDIT]:
I'm aware that the c++/c code is similar fast as my assembler code (actually it takes 19ms in c++ and 17ms in assembler). But I'm doing to learn assembler. I'm also aware that SIMD is faster but I wanted to learn the basic assembler first.

[EDIT2]:
added c++ and SIMD implemantation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
#define HT 240
#define WT 320
#define WTHT 76800
#define WT3 960
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock2;
typedef std::chrono::microseconds res;

int main() {

    clock2::time_point t1, t2 ,t3;  
uint32_t result = 0;
volatile uint8_t arr[WTHT];
for(int i=0;i<WT*HT;i++){
    arr[i]=9;   
}
arr[3]=7;
arr[4]=10;
arr[3+3*WT]=17;
t1 = clock2::now();
volatile uint8_t *pnt;
for(int iy=WT3;iy<(WTHT)-WT3;iy+=WT){
    pnt=&arr[iy+2];
    for(int ix=3;ix<WT-3;ix++){
    uint32_t resultlo = 0;
    uint32_t resulthi = 0;
    ++pnt;
    asm volatile( 
        //loading the center value in r0
        "ldrb r0, [%[in], #963]\n\t"
                //r0 forms the lower boundary
        "sub r0, r0,#8\n\t"
        //r2 forms the higher boundary
        "add r2,r0,#16\n\t"

        //Load of first pixel 3 pixel above center in r1
        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #3]\n\t"
        //compare r1 to lower boundary
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        //thumb it instruction add one to regLo if lower
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end1 \n\t"
        //compare r1 to higher boundary 
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        //thumb IT instruction add one to regHi if higher
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end1: \n\t"
        //shift both bitmasks by one
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        //analyze next pixel
        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #4]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end2 \n\t" 
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end2: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #325]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end3 \n\t" 
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end3: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #646]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end4 \n\t" 
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end4: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #966]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end5 \n\t" 
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end5: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #1286]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end6 \n\t" 
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end6: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #1605]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end7 \n\t" 
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end7: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #1924]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end8 \n\t" 
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end8: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #1923]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end9 \n\t" 
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end9: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #1922]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end10 \n\t"    
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end10: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #1601]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end11 \n\t"    
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end11: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #1280]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end12 \n\t"    
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end12: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #960]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end13 \n\t"    
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end13: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #640]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end14 \n\t"    
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end14: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #321]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end15 \n\t"    
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end15: \n\t"
        "lsl %[out],%[out],#1\n\t"
        "lsl %[outhi],%[outhi],#1\n\t"

        "ldrb r1, [%[in], #2]\n\t"
            "cmp r1,r0\n\t"
        "itt lo \n\t"
        "addlo %[out],%[out], #1\n\t"
        "blo end16 \n\t"    
        "cmp r1,r2\n\t"
        "it hi \n\t"
        "addhi %[outhi],%[outhi], #1\n\t"
        "end16: \n\t"
            :[out]"=r"(resultlo),[outhi]"=r"(resulthi): [in]"r" (pnt):"r0","r1","r2");
}
}
t2 = clock2::now();
std::cout << "Elapsed time is "
    << std::chrono::duration_cast<res>(t2-t1).count()<< "   microseconds.\n";


return 0;
}
```

**[c++]**

```
uint64_t r1=0;
    uint64_t r2=0;
    uint32_t result2=0;
    uint32_t result3=0;
    {
    for(int iy=WT3;iy<((WTHT)-WT3);iy+=WT){
    pnt=&arr[iy];
        for(int ix=3;ix<(WT-3);ix++){
            result2=0;
            result3=0;

            //get center point value
            const uint8_t c=*(pnt+963);
            //set lower bound
            const uint8_t l=c-8;
            //set upper bound
            const uint8_t h=c+8;
            //get first pixel value
            uint8_t p=*(pnt+3);
            //is it above uper bound 
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            //or maybe below lower bound
            } else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            //shift both
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            //set to next pixel value
            p=*(pnt+4);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+325);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;

            p=*(pnt+646);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+966);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+1286);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+1605);

            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+1924);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+1923);

            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+1922);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+1601);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+1280);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+960);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+640);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+321);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            p=*(pnt+2);
            if(p>h){
                ++result2;              
            }
             else if(p<l){
                ++result3;
            }
            result2=result2<<1;
            result3=result3<<1;
            //set pointer to next pixel
            ++pnt;              
            //prevent code part for beeing optimized out
            r1+=result2;
            r2+=result3;
        }
    }
}
```

**[SIMD or NEON instrincts]**

```
for(int iy=WT3;iy<((WTHT)-WT3);iy+=WT){
        pnt=&arr[iy-WT3];
        for(int ix=3;ix<(WT-3);++ix){
            //set center value
             uint8_t c1=*(pnt+963);
            //set lower bound
             uint8_t l1=c1-8;
            //set uper bound
             uint8_t h1=c1+8;
            //load all values from circle in one array
            uint8_t ps1[16]={*(pnt+3),*(pnt+4),*(pnt+325),*(pnt+646),
                    *(pnt+966),*(pnt+1286),*(pnt+1605),*(pnt+1924),
                    *(pnt+1923),*(pnt+1922),*(pnt+1601),*(pnt+1280),
                    *(pnt+960),*(pnt+640),*(pnt+321),*(pnt+2)};
            //load this array in neon register  
            uint8x16_t t1=vld1q_u8(ps1);

            //Load one uint8x16 vector with same value (higher bound)
            uint8x16_t hl1 =vld1q_dup_u8(&h1);
            //Load one uint8x16 vector with same value (lower bound)
            uint8x16_t ll1 =vld1q_dup_u8(&l1);
            //Vector compare less-than
            uint8x16_t rl=vcltq_u8(t1,ll1);
            //Vector compare greater-than
            uint8x16_t rh=vcgtq_u8(t1,hl1);
            ++pnt;
        }
    }
```

It would be great if you could point me to some optimiziations I could do to that code to make it run faster

Excution time for 
assembler is 17ms
c/c++ with O2 flag:19ms
SIMD:44ms

Comment: The most obvious suggestion would be "don't write it in inline assembly". There's nothing there that can't be trivially expressed in C++, and the general rule is that the compiler is better at optimising than you are.

Comment: Another obvious suggestion is that if you're not using SIMD, you're not using one of the best ways to get maximum performance.

Comment: "I'm aware that the c++/c code is similar fast as my assembler code (actually it takes 19ms in c++ and 17ms in assembler). But I'm doing to learn assembler. I'm also aware that SIMD is faster but I wanted to learn the basic assembler first."  --- You should at least post your c/c++ code, then. Most people will not even bother reading your assembly code in the absence of the reference ('human-readable') code.

Comment: My 'obvious suggestion' is to not modify registers in your asm without telling the compiler.  I see you modify (at least) r0, r1, r2, r5 and r6 without clobbering them.  While this might seem to work, it is dangerous.  Also, %[out] already represents a register.  Why not use that register instead of r6?  You don't know which register the compiler might pick, but you can always use %[out].  Lastly, I'd add the memory clobber to avoid issues with `arr`.  These issues tend to disappear if you use an assembler routine instead of inline assembler (see the ARM abi), which is what I'd recommend.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd ok thanks. I used inline assembler because I expected the code to be much shorter. Now I think it's still good for a learning effect. I changed now r5 and r6 to be outhi and outlo as you said and added the rest  of the register to clobber list. But could you help me on the clobber list with memory as I don't understand it fully I guess. Until now I just thought it's meant to signal which registers are needed.

Comment: Using inline asm is probably the most difficult possible way to learn asm.  There are all sorts of weird rules and gotchas.  That said, there's a good description of clobbers [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers).